# Invalid literal for float() in Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am working on a dataset with more than 60M rows in Pandas. In one of my numeric columns, I suspect that there is a non-numeric char which gives me the error message "invalid literal for float(): 4010146209+".

I am able to load the column as obj but not as float or int.

I have tried replacing r"\d" and "+" with "".

I need to either remove rows with non-numeric char in defined column or remove all char keeping the column from being loaded as float or int.

The column contains NaN, but these are dropped before I try to cast as float.

Comment: Why would you replace `r"\d"`? That will remove all the numbers. You should replace `r"\D"`, that matches everything except numbers.

Answer (score 2):

i would use [to_numeric()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) function for that

demo

```
In [583]: a
Out[583]:
0                         50.5
1                         50.7
2                         50.9
3                       52.70+
4                         52.9
5                       520.31
6    really bad number: 520.92
Name: Price, dtype: object

In [584]: a = pd.to_numeric(a, errors='coerce')

In [585]: a
Out[585]:
0     50.50
1     50.70
2     50.90
3       NaN
4     52.90
5    520.31
6       NaN
Name: Price, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`.replace()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) with a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html) to keep the numeric values rather than converting to `np.nan` using `pd.to_numeric`:

```
df['col_name'].replace(to_replace='[^0-9]+', value='',inplace=True,regex=True)
```